# Spring Boot change value properties file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Hi I'm using spring boot. I would like to dynamically replace the contents of a variable in the properties file.

This is my file: `message.properties`

```
message=Welcome ${bean.name}  to my website
```

I would like to know if there is any way to change the value of my variable.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it comes to `messages.properties` file, you don't have to change dynamically its content. Instead you can use message variables. Take a look at this example:

**messages.properties:**

```
message=Welcome {0} to my website
```

If you process that message using `MessageSource` bean, you can get this message with:

```
messageSource.getMessage("message", new Object[] { "Test" }, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale())
```

The returned string in that case is:

```
Welcome Test to my website
```

Of course you need to inject `MessageSource` to the class (controller,service) before you can use this exemplary code:

```
@Autowired
MessageSource messageSource
```

Comment: Thanks :) now really works. They were three days that I could not find a solution. thanks again

Comment: Hey @Diego, I'm glad I could help you :) Feel free to accept my answer, I'll really appreciate it :)